# How to add Categories to the top menu of the website?

Tags: categories, menus

How can I add links to the categories (for example, Category-1) to the top menu of my WordPress blog? Only Pages appear here.

[image: top menu from my blog]

Comment: Please let us know what version of wordpress you are using.

Comment: Also if you are using a custom theme and if you are aware that your theme is WP 3.0+ compliant.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add categories with Appearance -> Menus. They are listed in the block below 'pages':

[image]

Comment: And if not already enabled, should be under **"Screen options"**..